# Calculate $P(|X-{1\over 2}|>{1\over 4})$

Tags: probability

I was wondering if someone could check my work?
Let X be a continuous random variable with density function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 6x(1-x) & \text{ for }0<x<1 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

$$\text{Calculate }P(|X-{1\over 2}|>{1\over 4})$$

I did, $$x-{1\over2}>{1\over 4}\text{ so then }x>{3\over 4} $$or$${1\over 2} - x> {1\over 4}\text{ so then }x<{-1\over 4}\text{ which can't be true so it has to be the one above.}$$So then I have $$\int_{3\over 4}^1(6x-6x^2)dx=.15625$$

Comment: The condition $|x-\frac{1}{2}|>\frac{1}{4}$ implies $x > \frac{3}{4}$ or $x < \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: dang, you're right. So then I just need to add another integral on?
Edit: Shouldn't it just double it since it's uniform and I'm traversing the same amount of distance on both ends?

Comment: You are correct that you need to add another integral. You are incorrect about it being 'uniform' - you mean 'symmetrical about $x=\frac 12$'. You are correct about it being the same value - so you can just double what you already have.

Comment: You can use a diagram to aid you (make it more apparent): $\mathbb{P}(X > \frac{3}{4} \cup X < \frac{1}{4})$ is the integral over the whole domain (which will equal 1), minus the integral from $\frac{1}{4} $to $\frac{3}{4}$ of the probability distribution function.

Answer (score 0):

$|X-\frac{1}{2}|>\frac{1}{4}\Rightarrow X>\frac{3}{4}$ or $X<\frac{1}{4}$. So we have $P[|X-\frac{1}{2}|>\frac{1}{4}]=P[X>\frac{3}{4} \bigcup X<\frac{1}{4}]=1-P[\frac{1}{4}\leq X\leq \frac{3}{4}]=1-\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{3}{4}} 6x(1-x)dx=1-\frac{5}{8}=\frac{3}{8}$